# Using Rectangle.Intersects for Collision detection causes objects to "stick" to surfaces (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a top - down shooter game. Currently I am doing everything from scratch because I want to learn Java better. My problem right now is with collision detection. I am using Rectangle.Intersects(as seen in code) to determine whether the player is intersecting with walls. It almost perfectly, except that when the player is colliding on just one axis (ie running into a vertical wall), they are locked in both directions. I want to implement sliding for more smooth gameplay.

I have a slight idea on how to do this, which would involve checking the x and y planes individually. However, I don't know if this is possible using my current method.

I am a little new to Java so I don't know much about different kinds of libraries I could use instead of Rectangles but they have been working great and I would like to stick to them.

If there is a solution using Rectangles, that would be great. If there isn't, I'm open to new ideas.

Thanks.

Here is the code I am using

```
//x and y are position of player and vx and vy are the velocities in respective directions
public void tick() {
    x+=vx;
    y+=vy;

    collision();
    //movement
    //...
}
private void collision() {
    for(int i = 0; i< handler.object.size(); i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Block) {
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {
                x +=-vx;
                y +=-vy;
            }

        } //...
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle((int)x,(int)y,32,32);
}
```

Comment: You reset the position of the object, based on the amount it's move, but don't seem to change the delta values, so the collision will continue to occur, as an observation

Comment: thanks, this helped me solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone reading this is curious, I made a new function that handles movement and converted collision into a boolean that returns true if player is colliding with blocks (walls) and false if colliding with anything else.

I also change the check for the block collision, as seen in the code

```
private boolean collision(double vx, double vy) {
    for(int i = 0; i< handler.object.size(); i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Block) {
            if(new Rectangle((int)x+(int)vx,(int)y+(int)vy,31,31).intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {
                    return true;
                }
            } 
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Crate) {
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {
                main.ammo+=50;
                handler.removeObject(tempObject);
            }
        }   
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Enemy) {
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {
                main.hp--;//TODO make it so you cant get stuck in enemies and they drain all your health
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and the move function

```
public void Move(double vx, double vy) {
    if(!collision(vx,vy)) {
        x+=vx;
        y+=vy;
    }

}
```

the tick method is also slightly altered

```
public void tick() {    

    collision(vx,vy);

    vx = 0;
    vy = 0;
    //movement
    if(handler.isUp()) vy -=5;
    //else if(!handler.isDown()) vy = 0;

    if(handler.isDown()) vy += 5;
    //else if(!handler.isUp()) vy = 0;

    if(handler.isRight()) vx += 5;
    //else if(!handler.isLeft()) vx = 0;

    if(handler.isLeft()) vx -=5;
    //else if(!handler.isRight()) vx = 0;

    if(vx!=0||vy!=0){
        Move(vx,0);
        Move(0,vy);
    }
    //anim.runAnimation();
}
```